# iOS: How do I store a value (Integer) that I want to use as part of a calculation in several classes?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a value that I want to store. By default it is 14. I have a text field that a user would input their own value perhaps 5, 10, or 20. I need that value stored (every time they open the app, too) to be used across 3 different classes.

What's the best approach? Settings Bundle? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults`.

### int

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:[NSNumberNumberWithInt:5] 
                                      forKey:@"kPlus"];
```

### float

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:[NSNumberNumberWithFloat:5.2] 
                                      forKey:@"kMinus"];
```

The same method method can be used for `double`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setDouble:2.1234  
                                      forKey:@"kMultiply"];
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should I put this? Does it need to be in the application didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method?

Comment: Wherever you plan to store the value. I don't know what your code looks like or what your project does. Just plug it in when you decide to actually use it is my best guess.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wasn't very descriptive. By default the int value will be 14 and be used on calculation on 3 different classes. I just wanted to know if I need to put this in as soon as the app launches and if it can then be called and changed throughout the app after. Thanks for answering my questions!

Comment: No problem, when you need to retrieve this value, use `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"kPlus"] intValue]`, same applies to **Float:** `floatValue`, etc.